# duplicate a set of objects instances that match the specific field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I am a newbie in mongodb, my second day of playing with this, and I would like to get some help for my question below!

I would like to duplicate or copy a set of objects instances that match the specific field, and then copy them and save them with new `ObjectId`s.

**Example**

```
db.getCollection('food').find( { food_type: "fruit" } )
```

The query above with show me 8 documents with 8 fields each: `food_type`, `name`, `description`, `color`, `origin`, `import_price`, `export_price`, `margin`.

I have 8 types of fruits, and the query

```
totalFoodTypes = db.getCollection('food').count( { food_type: "fruit" } )
```

will return 8. I would like to copy all these 8 documents into another brand new 8 documents with new `ObjectId`s and `food_type` field value changed to `Vegetable`. Is there an easy way for doing that?

My current best thinking is to store the result from

```
db.getCollection('food').find( { food_type: "fruit" } )
```

and then loop `totalFoodTypes` documents and insert them one by one with Java.

Would be really appreciated if mongodb has some shortcut for doing this.